# How to get the content of page after it's completely loaded

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that has to get the content of the page any time i open the page or navigate there. I use chrome.tabs.onUpdated with condition that changeInfo.status == 'complete. On some websites it works properly, however on the others the listener trigger more times than expected and as a result in my database i have stored multiple objects that contains only part of the page's content and only the object created after the last trigger has all the content.

backgroud.js

```
function getDom() {
  const pageContent = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
  return pageContent;
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, info, tab) => {
  if (info.status === 'complete') {
    const url = tab.url;  
    const user = client.authStore.model;
    if (user) {
      chrome.storage.local.get(['tracked_tabs'], function(result) {
        console.log(result.tracked_tabs);
        if (result.tracked_tabs.includes(tabId) && info.status === "complete") {
          chrome.scripting.executeScript(
            {
              target: {tabId: tabId},
              func: getDom,
            },
            (pageContent) => { 
              console.log(pageContent);
              create_new_entry(pageContent[0].result, url, user); 
            });
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "Project librarian",
    "description": "Prototype of the librarian project",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "src/scripts/background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "key": "###",
    "action": {
        "default_icon": {             
            "16": "icons/i16.png",   
            "24": "icons/i24.png",   
            "32": "icons/i32.png"   
        },
        "default_title": "Project Librarian",   
        "default_popup": "src/popup/popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "identity", "scripting", "webNavigation", "notifications"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "all_frames": true,
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["src/scripts/content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "options_page": "src/options/options.html",
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"]
```

Comment: onUpdated will trigger every time a page loads (or changes in the case of single page applications) ... Most apps nowadays are single page apps which causes onUpdated to trigger multiple times per page. The solution is simple: Don't use onUpdated. This functionality can be completed with a content_script. Just have the content script wait for DOMContent to load and then run your function.

Comment: Also, looks like you are using "tracked_tabs" as a dynamic variable, so you can run that same function in the content script and modify it to use document.URL or location.host, etc